# Vue Material Checkbox Checked

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-material

I have tried / guessed at every combination of v-bind/v-model/:checked/:value I can think of, but I can't get these damn checkboxes checked on load:

Using Vue Material / Vue3:

```html
    <div v-if="items.length">
      <div
        v-for="(value,key,index) in this.items"
        :key="index"
        :ref="'icon'+items[key].id">
        <md-checkbox
          :id="'TDS'+key"
          v-model="items[key].complete"
          true-value="1"
          @change="doDo(items[key].id)"
          class="md-primary m-0"
          >
          {{ items[key].item }} {{items[key].complete}}
        </md-checkbox>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The bit I can't figure out is how to make the checkbox checked if items[key].complete=1 when data is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This one should already work, if you receive your data properly, it may update itself due to reactivity. Maybe try `v-model="!!items[key].complete"` just to be sure that your value is coerced to a Boolean.

Comment: Two things - 1: I never saw double bang before, ace! 2: This answer + removing the true-value (obvs) made the checkboxes checked. The problem there was coercion. BUT - now when I check a box, the event fires (v simple method, just an Axios post), but the box doesn't check. Curious.

Comment: > "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'complete' in true" after click.

Comment: Looking at the official documentation [here](https://vuematerial.io/components/checkbox) It looks like you don't even need to have a `true-value` prop at all. Try removing it.

Comment: Thanks Kissu. I gave that a go and sadly no change. I -think- in the end it was probably down to checkboxes being bound to an object, but that object wasn't being updated by the change event that I was sending to the backend. Various attempts to fix that ended up in a loop so I gave up and replaced native checkboxes with a quick component made of icons instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are already inside the loop

```
v-model="value.complete"
```

Same goes for all other bindings.

And your data should not be accessed with `this` in your template

```
v-for="(value,key,index) in items"
```

Comment: Thanks for value.complete tip. Didn't know that.